Thread ID Mismatch and NullPointerException Problem in Parallel Tests Using ThreadLocal
I'm running a parallel test using TestNG and Cucumber. I'm managing the driver object with ThreadLocal. However, I noticed that the setDriver and getDriver methods are running on different thread IDs, which causes getDriver() to return null. The problem seems to be incompatibility between different threads in parallel tests.During debug, setDriver and getDriver are running on different thread IDs.When I disable parallel operation, the test works fine. However, ThreadLocal seems to be incompatible in parallel mode.
package utilities;

import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.android.options.UiAutomator2Options;

import java.net.URL;
import java.time.Duration;

public class DriverManager {

    private static ThreadLocal<AndroidDriver> driver = new ThreadLocal<>();

    public static void setDriver (String deviceName,String platformName,String platformVersion,String port) {
        if (driver.get() == null) {
            try {
                System.out.println("setDriver - Thread ID: " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
                UiAutomator2Options options = new UiAutomator2Options();
                options.setPlatformName(platformName);
                options.setPlatformVersion(platformVersion);
                options.setDeviceName(deviceName);
                options.setAppPackage(ConfigReader.getProperty("appPackage"));
                options.setAppActivity(ConfigReader.getProperty("appActivity"));
                options.setAutomationName("UiAutomator2");
                options.setNewCommandTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(3600));
                options.setAutoGrantPermissions(true);
                options.setApp(ConfigReader.getProperty("app"));
                options.setFullReset(true);
                String appiumServerURL = ConfigReader.getProperty("appiumServerURL");
                //String url="http://"+ConfigReader.getProperty("ip")+":"+port+"/wd/hub";
                AndroidDriver driverInstance = new AndroidDriver(new URL(appiumServerURL), options);
                driverInstance.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Duration.ofSeconds(10));
                driver.set(driverInstance);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                throw new RuntimeException("Driver başlatılamadı: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }

    public static AndroidDriver getDriver() {
        System.out.println("getDriver - Thread ID: " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
        return driver.get();
    }
    public static void quitDriver() {
        if (driver.get() != null) {
            driver.get().quit();
            driver.remove();
        }
    }



}


package utilities;

import io.cucumber.testng.AbstractTestNGCucumberTests;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Parameters;
public class TestBase extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests {

    @BeforeTest
    @Parameters({"deviceName","platformName","platformVersion","port"})
    public void beforeMethod(String deviceName,String platformName,String platformVersion,String port){
        try {
            System.out.println("TestNG: @BeforeTest çalıştı.");
            DriverManager.setDriver(deviceName,platformName,platformVersion,port);
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}


package runners;


import io.cucumber.testng.AbstractTestNGCucumberTests;
import io.cucumber.testng.CucumberOptions;
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
import utilities.TestBase;

@CucumberOptions(
        features = "src/test/resources/features",
        glue = {"steps","utilities"},
        plugin = {"pretty","html:target/cucumber-reports-testng.html"},
        monochrome = true,
        dryRun = false,
        tags = "@hepsiburada1"
)

public class TestNGRunner extends TestBase {
@Override
    @DataProvider(parallel = true)
    public Object[][] scenarios() { return super.scenarios(); }
}


package runners;


import io.cucumber.testng.AbstractTestNGCucumberTests;
import io.cucumber.testng.CucumberOptions;
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
import utilities.TestBase;

@CucumberOptions(
        features = "src/test/resources/features",
        glue = {"steps","utilities"},
        plugin = {"pretty","html:target/cucumber-reports-testng.html"},
        monochrome = true,
        dryRun = false,
        tags = "@hepsiburada2"
)

public class TestNGRunner2 extends TestBase {
    @Override
    @DataProvider(parallel = true)
    public Object[][] scenarios() { return super.scenarios(); }
}


Also, the Parameters anotation cannot see the parameters I gave in the testng.xml file
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Cucumber Test Suite" parallel="tests" thread-count="2">
    <test name="Cucumber Tests">
        <parameter name="deviceName" value="emulator-5554"></parameter>
        <parameter name="platformName" value="Android"></parameter>
        <parameter name="platformVersion" value="14.0"></parameter>
        <parameter name="port" value="4723"></parameter>
        <classes>
            <class name="runners.TestNGRunner" />
        </classes>
    </test>
    <test name="Cucumber Tests 2">
        <parameter name="deviceName" value="emulator-5556"></parameter>
        <parameter name="platformName" value="Android"></parameter>
        <parameter name="platformVersion" value="14.0"></parameter>
        <parameter name="port" value="4725"></parameter>
        <classes>
            <class name="runners.TestNGRunner" />
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>


That's somewhat expected. The @BeforeTest method runs once before all scenarios. As the scenarios run in parallel they'll be one different threads.
Instead inline the AbstractTestNGCucumberTests and store configuration for the web driver in the runner class. Then before each scenario executes, in the runScenario method create the web driver from the configuration stored in the runner closed.
